# Grouping companies and their deals

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to find out the number of deals between companies of a country in SQL:

Here are my tables Company and Deals

```
Company
================
companyname     country
A               US
B               US
C               UK
D               Russia  


Deals
================
id  sold bought total
1   A    B      50
2   B    C      100
3   C    A      150
4   D    B      200


Result:
============
country     sold    bought
US          150     200
UK          150     100
Russia      200     0
```

I have tried the below query that gets only sold items:

```
select country, sum(total) as sold 
from company c left join deals d on c.companyname=d.sold 
group by country.
```

How to write a query to get sold and bought results at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses subqueries

```
select country, sum(sold) as sold, sum(bought) as bought
from (select c.*,
             (select sum(d.total)
              from deals d
              where d.sold = c.companyname
             ) as sold,
             (select sum(d.total
              from deals d
              where d.bought = c.companyname
             ) as bought
      from company c
     ) c
group by country;
```

Answer (score 1):

using sub-query

```
select t1.country,t1.sold,t2.bought  from
(
select c.country,coalesce(sum(d.total),0) as  sold
 from company  c left join Deals d
on c.companyname=d.sold
group by c.country
) t1 left join

(
select c.country,coalesce(sum(d.total),0) as bought 
 from company  c left join Deals d
on c.companyname=d.bought 
c.country
) t2 on t1.country=t2.country
```